# Accessing TWinControl.Handle on TForm.Create

Tags: delphi

I have this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoSomethingWithCombobox(ComboBox1.Handle);
end;
```

Q: Is it **guaranteed** that the `ComboBox1.Handle` is always created on `TForm.FormCreate` (Form1 is the parent of ComboBox1)? Maybe on `OnFormShow`?
from my tests, it *seems* that the Handle is always available at that point.

I know that `ComboBox1.Handle` will call `HandleNeeded` at this point. but can I assume that Handle will always be available at this point?

I also know that the `TWincontrol` can **safely** access  it's own handle on `CreateWnd`. My question is specific to a scenario where I cannot control `CreateWnd` of the child control and only have access to the parent events/messages.

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: The handle is created on demand. It could well be recreated at a later date. Don't take a copy of it!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I know that. but is there a scenario where Handle returns 0 in my case? and if yes, why?

Comment: I don't think so. But recreation is the real concern. In other words, you are probably asking the wrong question. You have to account for recreation and it seems that you are not. The way to tackle that is to override the combo's `CreateWnd`.

Comment: You can safely access Combobox in overridden Parent (form) CreateWnd

Comment: @MBo But the combo's window can be recreated without the parent being recreated

Comment: @David Yes, but I see no problem - once created, combobox window exists (probably recreated) until destroyed.

Comment: @MBo If whatever is done using the handle needs to be reapplied, then it won't happen.

Comment: *" ... always be available at this point?"* - That point has no significance. It is before the creation of the native combobox control in its normal course, which is when the parent is made visible. Same for form's OnShow, it is before ShowWindow is called for the form's window.

Comment: What is guaranteed is that the VCL will call CreateWindowEx for a parentless combo when you refer to its handle, and that's all.

Comment: What is missing in all of this is what DoSomethingWithCombobox does.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be better to change `DoSomethingWithComboBox` to accept a `TComboBox` instead and forget mucking around with the handle entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tests show that it's OK to access the control's handle there, then it should be OK. You're the application developer, so if you later change anything to break that assumption, you'll also have the power to fix it.

Accessing a control's `Handle` property will either yield a valid window handle or throw an exception. You won't get a null handle. The exception would typically come when the control's parent window is unable to exist.

The handle you get at that point isn't guaranteed to be the last handle the control will ever have, because controls' underlying windows may be recreated, but since you're the application developer (as opposed to a component-library developer), you have reasonable control over how often windows will be recreated after the form has finished being created. This is because you're handling the `OnCreate` event. Had you been overriding the `Loaded` method, for example, there's be less confidence that all window-creation activity had finished.